# NGRX effect dispatched an invalid action

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I am trying to create an `@Effect()` for my action. When I run action with type `AuthenticationUserLoad` I get an error.

```
ERROR Error: Effect "AuthenticationEffects.getUser$" dispatched an invalid action: [object Object]
```

Here is my `Effect` code

```
    @Effect()
      getUser$ = this.actions$.pipe(
       ofType(AuthenticationUserActions.AuthenticationUserTypes.AuthenticationUserLoad),
       map((action) => {

          return this.authService.getUser().pipe(
            map((user: User) => new AuthenticationUserActions.AuthenticationUserLoadSuccess({user})),
            catchError(error => of(new AuthenticationUserActions.AuthenticationUserLoadFailure({error})))

          );
        })
     );
```

**UPDATE**

I changed `map` to `switchMap` and it works.

```
 @Effect()
  getUser$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(AuthenticationUserActions.AuthenticationUserTypes.AuthenticationUserLoad),
    switchMap((action) => {

      return this.authService.getUser().pipe(
        map((user: User) => new AuthenticationUserActions.AuthenticationUserLoadSuccess({user})),
        catchError(error => of(new AuthenticationUserActions.AuthenticationUserLoadFailure({error})))
      );
    })
  );
```

Maybe I dont understand the difference between map and switchMap.

Comment: please provide your `AuthenticationUserActions`

Comment: You can easily avoid this kind of issues by adding an explicit type to the declaration of `getUser$`. For example: `getUser$: Observable<Action> =...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`map` operator maps current value, it doesn't care whether it is an observable or not.
Whereas `switchMap` or `mergeMap` or `concatMap` expect a callback to return an observable value, subscribe to it and emits its values.

Therefore when you call `map` you say that current value should be transformed to some other.

```js
map(action => return this.authService.getUser()),
// here the value is an observable stream, but not its emits.
```

when you call `switchMap` you say now I want to subscribe to another stream and emit its values. Because it's `switchMap` it also says once the parent stream emits (the same action comes) unsubscribe from current child stream and subscribe again to what a new call of `this.authService.getUser()` returns.

```js
switchMap(action => return this.authService.getUser()),
// here the value is an emit from this.authService.getUser() stream.
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case adding the **{ dispatch: false }** in the action call solved it.

```
getUser$ = createEffect(() => 
    this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(actionName),
        withLatestFrom(this.store.select('app')),
        switchMap(() => {
            ...
        })
    ), { dispatch: false }
)
```